# Saving a model serializer with a nested relationship with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a something like the following:

```
class ClientSubscription(models.Model):

    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    subscription_date_start = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
    subscription_date_end = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('activity', 'client')
```

as well as the following serializers:

```
class ActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    activity_slug = serializers.CharField(read_only = True, required=False)
    activity_type = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only = True)
    activity_name = serializers.CharField(read_only = True, source = 'activity_type', required=False)\
    is_active = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ('id', 'activity_type', 'is_active', 'activity_name', 'activity_slug')

class ClientSubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    activity = ActivitySerializer(read_only=False)
    client = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Client.objects.all())
    subscription_date_start = serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d")
    subscription_date_end = serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d")

    class Meta:
        model = ClientConcernedSubscriptions
        fields = ('id', 'activity', 'client', 'subscription_date_start', 'subscription_date_end')
```

Everything in terms of serialization is going great - but I am not able to validate or save the deserialized data, and get the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'OrderedDict'
```

I have looked at [this](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2380), but I don't seem to be able to use this solution.

This is the received data:

```
{u'subscription_date_end': u'2015-10-01', 
'client': 8, 
u'subscription_date_start': u'2014-10-01', 
u'activity': {u'activity_name': u'Name', u'is_active': True, u'id': 14597, u'activity_slug': u'slug', u'activity_type': u'9'}, 
u'id': 58782}
```

I am sure this is something that must be fairly common to do, and that I am doing something stupid.  I would just like to be able to save my object, as well as to be able to alter fields on a related field.

Comment: You included the error, can you include the full traceback in your question? And the version of DRF that you are using?

Comment: Sorry, my traceback is identical to the github issue.  However, I cannot use the suggested solution - my only unique constraint is the activity/client pairing by primary keys, and I don't have access to that in the attrs parameter.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the unique validator in rest_framework expect a integer value for nested relations, if you make a custom serializer for a related field, the deserialization provides a dict instead the primary key value.

So i made this solution and hope helps you too.

Create a [Custom Validator](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#writing-custom-validators) like this:

```
class UniqueTogetherNestedValidator(object):

def __init__(
        self, queryset=None, simple_fields=None, dict_fields=None,
        message='Not unique together value'):
    if queryset is None or simple_fields is None or dict_fields is None:
        raise TypeError(
            '__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: \
\'queryset\', \'simple_fields\' and \'dict_fields\''
        )
    else:
        self.queryset = queryset
        self.simple_fields = simple_fields
        self.dict_fields = dict_fields
        self.message = message

def __call__(self, value):
    unique = {}
    for f in self.simple_fields:
        unique[f] = value[f]
    for f in self.dict_fields:
        unique['{}__id'.format(f)] = value[f]['id']
    print(unique)
    if self.queryset.filter(**unique).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError(self.message)
```

And then call it from the Meta in your serializer providing at least the queryset, simple_fields (fields from de model) and dict_fields (nested fields).